# ARRAYFORMULA with PERCENTRANK

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm looking to use `PERCENTRANK` in an `ARRAYFORMULA` for a column in a spreadsheet. I put the following formula in AB1.

```
={"Daily Total Ranking";arrayformula(if(isblank(A2:A),,PERCENTRANK($AB$2:$AB, AB2)))}
```

But the result is the same ranking (the one for cell AB2) down the entire column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the range of the whole column from AB2 onwards in the second PercentRank parameter so that the function is evaluated for each value in the range AB2:AB where A2:A is not blank, instead of just for AB2:

```
={"Daily Total Ranking";arrayformula(if(isblank(A2:A),,PERCENTRANK($AB$2:$AB, $AB$2:$AB)))}
```